# Hieroglyphs numerals

Tags: numbering, enumerate, counters

Can someone give me a hint how do I obtain **hieroglyphs numerals** 1--1000 in XeTeX?
I'm using this package:

```
\usepackage{hieroglf}
```

I need a macro with

\hg{\n} which prints \n in Hieroglyphs.

**EDIT**

Your solution is good, but for the fact that it already uses
incorrect character at number 1!

I need to accomplish these both things at once: to correct the starting number according to the snippet below and to extend the following sequence of roman,arabic,babyloniannum to
**hieroglyphs**. My base will be 10.

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that, in XeTeX, you can omit the package and use the [Unicode characters for heiroglyphs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Unicode/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs) from any font that supports them.

Comment: Could you please provide me with MWE to obtain an answer for my **EDIT** ?

Comment: I’m afraid I might need to ask you to wait on that.

Comment: @Davislor I will wait. I'll be happy to hear the answer sometime.

Comment: I think we shouldn't use the comment under [Peter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511111/194703) to communicate. I updated the answer to be employable in lists and so on. I have not the faintest idea about unicode. The answer works also with PDFLaTeX, which I consider a feature. What I could, however, offer is to make the answer shorter by employing e.g. `xint`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I'm afraid you cannot do at a reasonably simple way what Unicode can do easily. I just do not know the right way to do it. Should I ask new question with emphasis on the keyword Unicode? I appologize for your invested effort. And I'm using XeTeX anyway. Thank you for your interest! I think we all have learned a lesson.

Comment: You are definitely right when you say that I won't have anything to say on unicode. The decision on whether or not it is appropriate to ask a separate question is to be decided by you. (May I could mention that in its original version there was no mention of this, which is why I started looking at this problem, but this is not too important.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I've asked a new question. I'm much obliged to you for your great work. It was an interesting evening for me with a lot of surprises. I didn't realize that the magic of Unicode is so profound.The question is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511121/hieroglyphs-in-unicode-in-a-reasonably-simple-way)

Comment: You're welcome but you may (a) link to this post and (b) give more precise instructions. I take that you consider my answer too complicated. Fair enough, but I didn't get any information on whether you'd be OK with extra packages, which would allow one to make the answer *way* shorter.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat You seem to be a good programmer. Could you please have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511287/constant-counter-is-not-working) and tell me why the macro `jednotky{22}` prints the correct value BUT when given in `\hg\hgunits` an error occurs?

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**: Thanks for posting an MWE. Here is something that does that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\newcounter{hieroaux}
\newcounter{hierocurr}
\newcommand{\HieroDigit}[1]{\ifcase#1
\or
\Hone
\or
\Hten
\or
\Hhundred
\or
\Hthousand
\or
\HXthousand
\or
\HCthousand
\or
\Hmillion
\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand\hg[1]{\setcounter{hierocurr}{#1}%
\ifnum\value{hierocurr}>999999
 \setcounter{hieroaux}{0}%
 \loop\stepcounter{hieroaux}\textpmhg{\HieroDigit{7}}%
 \ifnum\value{hieroaux}<\the\numexpr(\value{hierocurr}-500000)/1000000\relax%
 \repeat%
 \setcounter{hierocurr}{\the\numexpr\value{hierocurr}-\value{hieroaux}*1000000}%
\fi
\ifnum\value{hierocurr}>99999
 \setcounter{hieroaux}{0}%
 \loop\stepcounter{hieroaux}\textpmhg{\HieroDigit{6}}%
 \ifnum\value{hieroaux}<\the\numexpr(\value{hierocurr}-50000)/100000\relax%
 \repeat%
 \setcounter{hierocurr}{\the\numexpr\value{hierocurr}-\value{hieroaux}*100000}%
\fi%
\ifnum\value{hierocurr}>9999
 \setcounter{hieroaux}{0}%
 \loop\stepcounter{hieroaux}\textpmhg{\HieroDigit{5}}%
 \ifnum\value{hieroaux}<\the\numexpr(\value{hierocurr}-5000)/10000\relax%
 \repeat%
 \setcounter{hierocurr}{\the\numexpr\value{hierocurr}-\value{hieroaux}*10000}%
\fi%
\ifnum\value{hierocurr}>999
 \setcounter{hieroaux}{0}%
 \loop\stepcounter{hieroaux}\textpmhg{\HieroDigit{4}}%
 \ifnum\value{hieroaux}<\the\numexpr(\value{hierocurr}-500)/1000\relax%
 \repeat%
 \setcounter{hierocurr}{\the\numexpr\value{hierocurr}-\value{hieroaux}*1000}%
\fi%
\ifnum\value{hierocurr}>99
 \setcounter{hieroaux}{0}%
 \loop\stepcounter{hieroaux}\textpmhg{\HieroDigit{3}}%
 \ifnum\value{hieroaux}<\the\numexpr(\value{hierocurr}-50)/100\relax%
 \repeat%
 \setcounter{hierocurr}{\the\numexpr\value{hierocurr}-\value{hieroaux}*100}%
\fi%
\ifnum\value{hierocurr}>9
 \setcounter{hieroaux}{0}%
 \loop\stepcounter{hieroaux}\textpmhg{\HieroDigit{2}}%
 \ifnum\value{hieroaux}<\the\numexpr(\value{hierocurr}-5)/10\relax%
 \repeat%
 \setcounter{hierocurr}{\the\numexpr\value{hierocurr}-\value{hieroaux}*10}%
\fi%
\ifnum\value{hierocurr}>0
 \setcounter{hieroaux}{0}%
 \loop\stepcounter{hieroaux}\textpmhg{\HieroDigit{1}}%
 \ifnum\value{hieroaux}<\value{hierocurr}\relax%
 \repeat%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\hg{\value{section}}}
\section{Examples}

$5=\hg{5}$\par
$36=\hg{36}$\par
$2357468=\hg{2357468}$\par
$\hg{7}\cdot\hg{6}=\hg{42}$\par
$\displaystyle\frac{\hg{3131}}{\hg{101}}=\hg{31}$\par
$\pi=\hg{3}.\hg{14159}$


\section{Numbered lists}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\hg{\value{enumi}}}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item A
 \item B
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLD (AND COMPLETELY UNEGYTIAN) ANSWER**: I'd like to start by saying that I have no idea whatsoever about hieroglyphs. This is just for fun. I copied some of the hieroglyphs from the `hieroglf` package source. Since there was a block of 74+1 of them, this gives you numerals with base 74. If you want another base, please provide an MWE from which I can learn what the appropriate digits and base are. Other than that I added a clumsy modulo and int function that does not need extra packages. If you want to make this more elegant, you may want to specify if you are OK with loading `xint` or `pgf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\newcommand\HieroGlf[1]{\ifcase#1
\Hdual
\or
\HAi
\or
\HAii
\or
\HAxxviii
\or
\HCxi
\or
\HDi
\or
\HDii
\or
\HDiv
\or
\HDxxi
\or
\HDxxxvi
\or
\HDxlvi
\or
\HDxlvii
\or
\HDl
\or
\HDliv
\or
\HDlviii
\or
\HExxiii
\or
\HFi
\or
\HFxx
\or
\HFxxxi
\or
\HFxxxiv
\or
\HFxl
\or
\HGi
\or
\HGxvii
\or
\HGxxvi
\or
\HGxxvis
\or
\HGxxvii
\or
\HGxxviii
\or
\HGxxxvi
\or
\HGxliii
\or
\HHviii
\or
\HIviii
\or
\HIix
\or
\HIx
\or
\HKi
\or
\HMiii
\or
\HMviii
\or
\HMxii
\or
\HMxvii
\or
\HNxxix
\or
\HNxxxv
\or
\HNxxxvii
\or
\HOi
\or
\HOiv
\or
\HOxxxiv
\or
\HQiii
\or
\HRvii
\or
\HSxii
\or
\HSxxix
\or
\HSxxxix
\or
\HSxli
\or
\HTiii
\or
\HTxiv
\or
\HUxxxvi
\or
\HVi
\or
\HViv
\or
\HVxiii
\or
\HVxx
\or
\HVxxiv
\or
\HVxxviii
\or
\HVxxxi
\or
\HWxi
\or
\HXi
\or
\HYiV
\or
\HYiv
\or
\HZi
\or
\HZii
\or
\HZiv
\or
\HZvi
\or
\HZvii
\or
\HZxi
\or
\HAai
\or
\HAaxii
\or
\HPWi
\or
\HPWii
\fi}
\newcommand{\hieronumeral}[1]{\edef\temp{#1}%
\ifnum\the\numexpr\temp/(74*74)>1%
\textpmhg{\HieroGlf{\the\numexpr\temp/(74*74)-1}}%
\edef\temp{\the\numexpr\temp-74*74*\the\numexpr\temp/(74*74)-1\relax}%
\fi%
\ifnum\the\numexpr(\temp+37)/74>1%
\textpmhg{\HieroGlf{\the\numexpr(\temp+37)/74-1}}%
\edef\temp{\the\numexpr\temp-74*\the\numexpr(\temp+37)/74-1\relax}%
\else%
\ifnum#1>74%
0%
\fi%
\fi%
\textpmhg{\HieroGlf{\temp}}}
\begin{document}
$123=\hieronumeral{123}$ 

\newcounter{iloop}
\setcounter{iloop}{0}
\loop\stepcounter{iloop}
$\number\value{iloop}=\hieronumeral{\number\value{iloop}}$,
\ifnum\number\value{iloop}<999\repeat%
$1000=\hieronumeral{1000}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the MWE? Not in the question?

Comment: @cfr I meant to write MEOW. ;-) You're right, there is no MWE, and there has never been one, but at least some important information was added.

Comment: Well, they did like cats, I know.

Comment: @cfr When the climate is too hot for marmots, one starts worshipping cats instead.

Answer (score 3):

@user2925716 sent me an email about this and I responded with some information and suggested asking here, not realising that he had already done so. This is not a complete answer but might help others give one.

The Egyptians used the decimal numbering system. The `hieroglf` package provides glyphs for numbers, `\Hone` for units, `\Hten` for tens, `\Hhundred` for hundreds. The Egyptians repeated the glyphs to make up the required number.

The only example I have seen is of the number 28 where there were 2 `\Hten`
glyphs on top of 4 `\Hone` glyphs on top of 4 `\Hone` glyphs making a stack of three sets of glyphs.

I don't know how the number, say 39, should be represented. I understand that the representation of 234 should consist of 2 of `\Hhundred`, 3 of `\Hten` and 4 of `\Hone` but how the glyphs should be ordered within the document I do not know. I guess that it is a matter of aesthetics and may well depend on how the adjacent glyphs are laid out.

It seems that you might need some code that converts a number into the required number of glyphs, which I assume somebody can do for you, but then these need to be assembled into something that the Egyptians would recognize as a number. Perhaps up to you?

Comment: Unicode has those precomposed glyphs for Egyptian digits.  For example, 6,000 is U+131C1. XeTeX can use them with `fontspec.

Comment: Thanks for that information! +1 I wish I had seen that earlier before I posted the second version of my answer...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat That's my fault, sorry. I should have emphasized that I was using XeTeX. In fact I started to use it just because I needed other strange numerals.

Comment: @user2925716 No worries! It was fun learning something about Egyptian numerology. ;-)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat So could you now please finally give me a **general** way how to index Hieroglyphs in this style `\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!}` with Unicode and XeTeX ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `fontspec` and `expl3`.  It’s not very compact, but in my opinion, it’s a lot more readable than the legacy solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% These fonts are available at: http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/
\newfontfamily\hieroglyphfont{Aegyptus}[Scale = MatchUppercase, Script={Egyptian Hieroglyphs}]
\newfontfamily\emojifont{Symbola}[Scale = MatchUppercase] % The modern equivalent.

\newcommand\shrug{{{\emojifont\symbol{"1F937}}}}
\newcommand\EgyptianShrug{{\hieroglyphfont }}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_new:N \c_up_to_seven_digits_regex
\regex_set:Nn \c_up_to_seven_digits_regex { ^\d{1,7}$ }

\cs_new:Npn \hiero_numeral:n #1
  {
    \regex_match:NnTF
      \c_up_to_seven_digits_regex
      {#1}
      {
         \begingroup\hieroglyphfont
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {1000000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {% This is anachronistic; ancient Egyptians did not typically write 
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {100000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {% Also anachronistic.
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {10000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {1000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {100}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {10}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {#1} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \endgroup
      }
      {\shrug\EgyptianShrug}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hiero_numeral:n { e }

\newcommand\hg[1]{\hiero_numeral:e{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hg{1132641} (1132641)

\hg{4037} (4037)

\hg{NaN} (NaN)

\end{document}
```

[image: Aegyptus Sample]