# Hieroglyphs in Unicode-in a reasonably simple way

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode

I need to extend the following sequence of roman,arabic,babyloniannum to
**hieroglyphs**. The solution for LaTeX has been given [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511099/hieroglyphs-numerals)
but is very cumbersome. Also, it doesn't do the grouping of numerals
of the same class.

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!}
```

**I'm looking for a Unicode with the use of XeTeX version which should be very straightforward.
That is in at most **ordinary** 5 lines of code.**

**EDIT** This question is *not* a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511099/hieroglyphs-numerals)
at all. The answer there *doesn't use Unicode* which I expect
to use *here*. Tha author of the answer there has stated in fact
that he is unable to write an Unicode answer to my problem.

More precisely I need to use that Unicode has those precomposed glyphs for Egyptian digits. For example, 6,000 is U+131C1. XeTeX can use them with `fontspec`. **But** I do not know how do I create this U+131C1 in my
file ideje.tex. I hope the situation is clearer now?

[image]

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Most of the code in the linked answer could be put into a package and therefore the fact that it appears cumbersome to you is irrelevant. The grouping problem would be better described with a minimal example using that code and showing what the desired output would be. Furthermore, the issue seems to have very little to do with Unicode, other than the source of the glyphs themselves, which has nothing to do with generating the correct sequence of them corresponding to a number. And stating a maximum!? number of lines of code makes no sense.

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of, or at most a comment on, the question you just asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511099/hieroglyphs-numerals

Comment: You can put that code into 5 lines if you like. Or 1 line, for that matter.

Comment: @cfr I mean an *average* lines, not lines with 1000+ characters.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: @AlanMunn I need something like `\char"0105` and `\usepackage{fontspec}` for my numerals 1-1000 in Egyptian hieroglyphs.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "how do I create this U+131C1 in my file ideje.tex" that seems to be just a question about your editor, you can just type it in as character data () or use `^^^^131c1` tex notation, or `\symbol{"131C1}` for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've tried this: \item K \symbol{"131C1} L *but* there is nothing between K and L in the output. Perhaps some font needs to be installed? From where can I download it? I also need a macro \newcommand{\hiergolyph}[1]{#1} which will return \symbol{"131C1} when called with \hieroglyph{6000}.

Comment: well clearly you need a font with the characters, I have no idea which (but I assume any google search for these characters would suggest a suitable font. On my windows machine here firefox shows the character that I used in the previous comment with `Segoe UI Historic` (which I think is a standard Windows font, so I could use that in xetex via fontspec.

Comment: also I would remove the 5 lines of code comment which seems very strange, if you want to map 6000 to hex 131C1 and similarly the other values then that alone is likely to take a few dozen lines (as you will need to list the values, not some simple formula) then if you want to implement the grouping code then (a) you need to specify more how the grouping layout should work and (b) it is likely to take a hundred or so lines, so your question is probably not answerable given the constraints you place on the answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The grouping is already done by Unicode isn't it? Also there may well be some package `\usepackage` which could do 6000->131C1?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just do not know what exactly should I look for in google, e.g. which ending of the file ? `ttf` or something else? Even `Segoe UI Historic` doesn't look for nothing in google.

Comment: I just meant search for "hieroglyphs font" or some such. But if you can see the character between () in my comment above then you already have a font, you can use your browser inspector (right menu inspect element in firefox) to see what font it is using

Comment: Does unicode do the grouping? How? if you would accept a package that does the mapping of the numbers then the 5 line comment really makes no sense at all as any code given can be saved to a  package, and there are very few packages with less than 5 lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  You seem to be a good programmer. Could you please have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511287/constant-counter-is-not-working) and tell me why the macro `jednotky{22}` prints the correct value BUT when given in `\hg\hgunits` an error occurs?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Can you please explain [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511441/newline-after-hbox-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph) to me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

I had to guess some of the unicode mappings, just looking at

https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U13000.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hg{Segoe UI Historic}

\def\hgunits#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0133fa\or
^^^^^^0133fb\or
^^^^^^0133fc\or
^^^^^^0133fd\or
^^^^^^0133fe\or
^^^^^^0133ff\or
^^^^^^013400\or
^^^^^^013401\or
^^^^^^013402\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtens#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013386\or
^^^^^^013387\or
^^^^^^013388\or
^^^^^^013389\or
^^^^^^01338a\or
^^^^^^01338b\or
^^^^^^01338c\or
^^^^^^01338d\or
^^^^^^01338e\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundreds#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013362\or
^^^^^^013363\or
^^^^^^013364\or
^^^^^^013365\or
^^^^^^013366\or
^^^^^^013367\or
^^^^^^013368\or
^^^^^^013369\or
^^^^^^01336a\else
?\fi}

\def\hgthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0131bc\or
^^^^^^0131bd\or
^^^^^^0131be\or
^^^^^^0131bf\or
^^^^^^0131c0\or
^^^^^^0131c1\or
^^^^^^0131c2\or
^^^^^^0131c3\or
^^^^^^0131c4\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtenthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0130ad\or
^^^^^^0130ae\or
^^^^^^0130af\or
^^^^^^0130b0\or
^^^^^^0130b1\or
^^^^^^0130b2\or
^^^^^^0130b3\or
^^^^^^0130b4\or
^^^^^^0130b5\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundredthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\else
?\fi}

\def\hgnum#1{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}
\def\hgnumx#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
\hghundredthousands{#3}%
\hgtenthousands{#4}%
\hgthousands{#5}%
\hghundreds{#6}%
\hgtens{#7}%
\hgunits{#8}%
}
\begin{document}


152123

{\hg
\hghundredthousands{1}%
\hgtenthousands{5}%
\hgthousands{2}%
\hghundreds{1}%
\hgtens{2}%
\hgunits{3}%
}

\hgnum{152123}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine! However see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511180/hueroglyphs-in-unicode-4th-part-the-firefox-case).

Comment: You have typos in the definition of \hgtens ;-)

Comment: I blame  @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 0):

I’ll repost [my answer using Unicode.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511390/61644)  It’s not as terse as requested, because it uses expl3, but neither is David Carslisle’s fine answer.

Here is a solution using `fontspec` and `expl3`.  It’s not very compact, but in my opinion, it’s a lot more readable than the legacy solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% These fonts are available at: http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/
\newfontfamily\hieroglyphfont{Aegyptus}[Scale = MatchUppercase, Script={Egyptian Hieroglyphs}]
\newfontfamily\emojifont{Symbola}[Scale = MatchUppercase] % The modern equivalent.

\newcommand\shrug{{{\emojifont\symbol{"1F937}}}}
\newcommand\EgyptianShrug{{\hieroglyphfont }}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\regex_new:N \c_up_to_seven_digits_regex
\regex_set:Nn \c_up_to_seven_digits_regex { ^\d{1,7}$ }

\cs_new:Npn \hiero_numeral:n #1
  {
    \regex_match:NnTF
      \c_up_to_seven_digits_regex
      {#1}
      {
         \begingroup\hieroglyphfont
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {1000000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {% This is anachronistic; ancient Egyptians did not typically write 
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {100000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {% Also anachronistic.
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {10000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {1000}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {100}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {\int_div_truncate:nn {#1} {10}} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \int_to_symbols:nnn
           { \int_mod:nn {#1} {10} }
           {10}
           {
             {0}{}
             {1}{}
             {2}{}
             {3}{}
             {4}{}
             {5}{}
             {6}{}
             {7}{}
             {8}{}
             {9}{}
           }
         \endgroup
      }
      {\shrug\EgyptianShrug}
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \hiero_numeral:n { e }

\newcommand\hg[1]{\hiero_numeral:e{#1}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\hg{1132641} (1132641)

\hg{4037} (4037)

\hg{NaN} (NaN)

\end{document}
```

[image: Aegyptus Sample]