# Item enviroment with \hgnum command

Tags: enumerate, unicode, roman

I need to complete this numbering item enviroment from roman arabic to `\hgnum` in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511287/constant-counter-is-not-working)

```
\begin{enumerate}[ label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}--\hgnum{enumi}]
```

Here is the **MWE:**

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

 \usepackage{tikz-cd}

 \usepackage{fontspec}

 \usepackage[czech]{babel} \usepackage{mypackage}  

 \usepackage{babyloniannum} %\setfont{NewGardiner}
 \newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}

 \MakeRobust\babyloniannum \MakeRobust\hgnum \usepackage{enumitem}


   \begin{document}


 \underline{motto:}{ každý den $\pm$ nový princip }\hfill{$\square$} \\
 \\  \begin{enumerate}[
 label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!  \!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr
 "13000+\value{enumi}}--\hgnum{\value{enumi}}]   
 \item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého \GoodBye{A}   
\item *vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice) K{\hg \hgunits{5}}L   
\item svoboda a volnost
\item \hgnum{152123}
\item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please _always_ post self contained documents not just fragments that people have to reconstitute to see the issue. I wrote most of the answers in your (many) questions and I have no idea what \babyloniannum is and I can not guess how you have defined `\!` (the standard definition would give errors there)

Comment: you have tagged this question pdftex but the referenced answer defines code that can not work with pdftex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The `\!` alone works. It is supposed to do a negative space. Only when I add  `\hgnum{}` an error occurs. Perhaps I do not know the right arguments and surroundings of `\hgnum`

Comment: no `\!` will give an error about missing math mode, but I can not run your example as `\usepackage{babyloniannum}` and `\usepackage{mypackage} `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So just delete all `\!` together with `babylonyannum` and try to substitute the right form of `\hgnum` so that the hieroglyphic numbers appear at `\item`'s. The `\usepackage{mypackage}` is essentially your `\hgnum`: ^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\else
?\fi}

\def\hgnum#1{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}
\def\hgnumx#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%

Comment: no sorry it is your responsibility to ask a question with a reasonable example that does not require people to guess what code you are asking about, please edit the mwe so that it runs without error or if it gives an error, post the error message and ask about that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511337/item-enviroment-with-hgnum-command-2) if it meets your standard requiremnts to my OQ.

Comment: No! don't open yet another question _edit_ this one!! (or delete this one and just have the new one, if you prefer)

Comment: see how much easier it is to answer once you provide a test file:-)