# Item enviroment with \hgnum command 2

Tags: macros, xetex, enumerate, unicode

There 2 packages from my [last](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511299/item-enviroment-with-hgnum-command#comment1293027_511299) example:

ideje.tex and mypackage.tex

I need to complete this enumerate enviroment from arabic, roman to include **hgnum**

```
  begin{enumerate}[label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}--]%\hgnum{\value{enumi}}]
```

ideje.tex **MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{mypackage}
 \usepackage[czech]{babel}

 \newfontfamily\ngg{Segoe UI Historic}
 \usepackage{enumitem}

 \begin{document}

 \underline{motto:}{ každý den $\pm$ nový princip }\hfill{$\square$} \\
 \\  \begin{enumerate}[
 label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr
 "13000+\value{enumi}}--]%\hgnum{\value{enumi}}]
 \item rozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
\item *vždycky to tam máš (data v matematice) K{\hg \hgunits{5}}L
\item svoboda a volnost
\item \hgnum{152123}
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**mypackage.tex**

```
% this is my first package
%
% (c) Buffalo Bill
%
%% This program can be redistributed and/or modified under the terms
%% of the LaTeX Project Public License Distributed from CTAN archives
%% in directory macros/latex/base/lppl.txt.
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
  [2011/01/11 v0.01 LaTeX package for my own purpose]

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hg{Segoe UI Historic}

\def\hgunits#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0133fa\or
^^^^^^0133fb\or
^^^^^^0133fc\or
^^^^^^0133fd\or
^^^^^^0133fe\or
^^^^^^0133ff\or
^^^^^^013400\or
^^^^^^013401\or
^^^^^^013402\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtens#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013386\or
^^^^^^013387\or
^^^^^^013388\or
^^^^^^013389\or
^^^^^^01338a\or
^^^^^^01338b\or
^^^^^^01348c\or
^^^^^^01348d\or
^^^^^^01348e\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundreds#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013362\or
^^^^^^013363\or
^^^^^^013364\or
^^^^^^013365\or
^^^^^^013366\or
^^^^^^013367\or
^^^^^^013368\or
^^^^^^013369\or
^^^^^^01336a\else
?\fi}

\def\hgthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0131bc\or
^^^^^^0131bd\or
^^^^^^0131be\or
^^^^^^0131bf\or
^^^^^^0131c0\or
^^^^^^0131c1\or
^^^^^^0131c2\or
^^^^^^0131c3\or
^^^^^^0131c4\else
?\fi}

\def\hgtenthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^0130ad\or
^^^^^^0130ae\or
^^^^^^0130af\or
^^^^^^0130b0\or
^^^^^^0130b1\or
^^^^^^0130b2\or
^^^^^^0130b3\or
^^^^^^0130b4\or
^^^^^^0130b5\else
?\fi}

\def\hghundredthousands#1{\ifcase#1\relax\or
^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\or
^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190^^^^^^013190\else
?\fi}

\def\hgnum#1{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}
\def\hgnumx#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
\hghundredthousands{#3}%
\hgtenthousands{#4}%
\hgthousands{#5}%
\hghundreds{#6}%
\hgtens{#7}%
\hgunits{#8}%
}


%\RequirePackage{whateverwe need}
\def\hi{Hello, this is my own package}
\let\myDate\date
\newcommand\GoodBye[1][\bfseries]{{#1Good Bye}}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `mypackage.sty'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

declare `\hgnum` to be a robust command, change

```
\def\hgnum#1{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}
```

to

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\hgnum[1]{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}
```

Unrelated but you should delete the erroneous `\\` which are generating bad output and the warnings:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--22


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--22
```

Comment: It works fine now! Thank you!

Comment: It is inetersting that `\!` doesn't compile for you. For me it does: \begin{enumerate}[ label=\roman{enumi}--\arabic{enumi}--\!\!\!\!\!\babyloniannum{\value{enumi}}\!\!\!--\large\ngg\symbol{\numexpr "13000+\value{enumi}}--\hgnum{\value{enumi}}]

Comment: How do I achieve newline if I remove this: `\\\` ?

Comment: enumerate starts a new display anyway https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: on `\!` that is because now you have have provided a usable test file you are using `amsmath` which redefines `\!` the standard definition would give an error.

Comment: But I need 2 newlines `\\\` in a sequnece, starting enumerate gives one only.

Comment: Please, I'm trying hard to understand the number 10000000 in your `\DeclareRobustCommand\hgnum[1]{{\hg\expandafter\hgnumx\the\numexpr10000000+#1\relax}}` I've got familiar with `\expandafter` but that number is not clear to me yet.

Comment: @user2925716 imagine you want to pad a number to 4 digits but you might have 1 or 123 or 1234, simple way: add on 10000 then discard the leading 1 so 1->10001->0001, 123->10123->0123, 1234->11234->1234, this is same but forcing more digits

Comment: Yes, I understand now. And what does `\the` there